# How to route someone to a page when they click a button: React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsx

From what I understand "Link" has been replaced with "Route" and Im having trouble find a solid answer or solution.

When a user clicks a button I want them to be routed to another page in my app '/trade'

Heres what I have so far

```
<button className='btn-success btn btn-lg' onClick={<Route to='/trade' />}>Trade This Stock</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways.

using `useHistory`

```
import React from "react";
import {useHistory, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function NavigationExample() {
  const history = useHistory();
  console.log(history);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => history.push("/dashboard")} type="button">
        Click
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default withRouter(NavigationExample);
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import NavigationExample from "./NavigationExample";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavigationExample />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[Live Example in Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usehistory-example-rppfp)

> In above example, you import `useHistory` from `react-router-dom`. then take history object from `useHistory` and finally call `history.push` with url

using `Link`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function NavigationExample() {

return (
   <>
      <Link to={{pathname: '/dashboard'}}>Dashboard</Link>
   </>
  );
}
export default NavigationExample;
```

> In above example, you import `Link` from `react-router-dom`. then you need to set `to` with url

Comment: I like the use history approach more. I tried to implement it however its stating that its an error and its 'not imported from react router dom"

Comment: @user16645351 Please check answer part of useHistory. You need to do some trick. I added live example for codesandbox where you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate programmatically- react Tutorial

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#navigating-programmatically

```
import { useParams, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { getInvoice, deleteInvoice } from "../data";

export default function Invoice() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  let params = useParams();
  let invoice = getInvoice(parseInt(params.invoiceId, 10));

  return (
    <main style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
      <h2>Total Due: {invoice.amount}</h2>
      <p>
        {invoice.name}: {invoice.number}
      </p>
      <p>Due Date: {invoice.due}</p>
      <p>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            deleteInvoice(invoice.number);
            navigate("/invoices");
          }}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </p>
    </main>
  );
}
```